# How to properly store a 2D text file in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic, text-files, ifstream

I'm trying to read a text file into a 2D array. The rows and columns are listed in the first 2 lines of the text file so I just:

```
inFile >> rows;
inFile >> cols;
```

and that works fine.

However, whenever I initialize the array and print it...it doesn't come out properly. Why? There should be spaces in the maze but everything is filled with # like so:

```
# # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # s # # # 
e # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 
# # # # 

    void setArray(int rows, int cols)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = new string[cols];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                inFile >> grid[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902945/reading-a-string-from-file-c

Comment: is `string[cols]` an array of `std::string`? Have a look at how to make a [mcve]

Comment: Be detailed please, I cannot understand your question properly