# How can I read strings from a .txt file in a loop in C++

Tags: c++

My Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string index[8];

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    ifstream input;
    //input.open("passData.txt");
    while (true) {
        input.open("passData.txt");
        if (!input) {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {
            if (input.is_open()) {
                while (!input.eof()) {
                    input >> index[count];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                cout << index[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My approach: opening the file in the beginning and then close it as soon as the lines where read. Also every line should be a single entry in the array.

However, I get an error in a file called "xutility" in an iterator.
The output is the "passData.txt" file, only that its read once and then the error appears.

So, my question: how can I read every line of the file in an array entry, in a loop?

Thank you!

Comment: `input >> index[count];` reads a word (e.g. a string till a whitespace is found) and not a line.

Comment: `int count = 0;` should be defined inside `while(true){}` loop then press ctrl+c to exit. Do you want that infinite while loop?

Comment: Ok so apparently you are right. I forgot to reset the counter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902945/reading-a-string-from-file-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with this code is that you don't break the endless loop, like ever. Because of that you keep on incrementing the `count` and it finally goes out of range for your string array called `index`.

Comment: It does have an end: while(the endoffile isnt reached){increment} So thath cant be the problem :/

Comment: I meant the outer loop `while (true)`

Comment: Ok i read your answer again and from what i understand you might be right. I found the problem. As you said: the counter needs to be reset everytime the while loop starts over so that the array index starts at 0 evertyime we loop through.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code, I think it does your mission but it's simpler:

```
string strBuff[8];
int count = 0;
fstream f("c:\\file.txt", ios::in);
if (!f.is_open()) {
    cout << "The file cannot be read" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
while (getline(f, strBuff[count])) {
    count++;
}

cout << strBuff[3] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

When extracting from a stream, you should check the result, rather than testing beforehand.

You don't need to call `open`, the constructor that accepts a string does that. You don't need to call `close`, the destructor does that.

You should only output lines you have read.

Note that you should stop *both* if your file runs out of lines, or if you have read 8 lines

You can discard most of what you have written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string index[8];
    std::size_t count = 0;   
    for(std::ifstream input("passData.txt"); (count < 8) && std::getline(input, index[count]); ++count)
    { 
        // this space intentionally blank
    }
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << index[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```